# DDL queries (Table creation, index creation, etc) is too slow on postgres rds instance

Tags: postgresql, database-performance, amazon-rds, ddl, slowdown

Recently we are facing an issue in which all account creation (basically schema creation) becomes slow.

Postgres Information:

- Version: 9.4.4, server 9.4.7
- Database is located on: RDS instance
- No of database: 1
- No of schema - almost 1700
- No of tables in one schema - 415 tables

Problem: 
- When i am creating new schema... **schema creation is very slow**.

By closely looking the issue, I observed that

- All DDL queries (especially, when I am dealing with inherited tables) take
  too much time. (Create table, Create index, \d tablename...etc)
- E.g: For single table creation, it takes almost **8+ seconds**. (which is not acceptable at all)

Current Configuration of Postgres:

- work_mem: 8MB
- maintenance_work_mem: 896 MB

**Update:**

- We have also tried to set higher values(**work_mem=88MB, maintenance_work_mem=1920MB**)... but same result.

**Questions**:

- Is this the problem related to RDS? (Does RDS have any limitation/known problem?)
- Do we need to re-tune PostgreSQL configuration parameters?
- Is this problem related to Postgres' internal meta data? (system tables too slow?)
- Which could be possible solutions in this?

Comment: Have you watched your iops usage on your instance? Are you running out of the iops burst credits perhaps?

Comment: I checked it... It seems normal.  :(

Comment: It could be caused by bloated system tables. Did you turn off auto vacuum?

Comment: Nope. Auto vacuum is ON.  Also, autovacuum_max_workers=3.  (I am not sure this is right value or not.  Any idea for this value? )

Comment: do you run it over any connection pooler? (eg pgbouncer)

Comment: ddl are slow at once or after performing some amount of ddl fast and then speed drops?..

Comment: Nope... we do not use any pooler. (Even I am trying to create tables from command line... and it takes time.)

Comment: We have this problem since few(3-4) days... Prior to that it takes considerable time (between 0.5 to1.25 seciond)....but now it is almost 8 time slower than prior...